# Why the message don't appear on the page when MediaLibrary is used?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-medialibrary

I'm using Laravel nova also the ClassicO\NovaMediaLibrary\MediaLibrary.

And with Laravel Nova I can use the help method like this:

```
Select::make('Option')
                ->options(
                    Post::active()
                )->help(
                    'Please select a option'
                )
```

However using the same help() method and also the MediaLibrary like this:

```
  MediaLibrary::make('Image')
                ->help('Only png.')
                ->types(['Image']),
```

The help message don't appear on the page. Do you know what can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I checked their [documentation](https://github.com/classic-o/nova-media-library#usage) and it seems that they lack any mention of such feature that displays the "note" under the field. So I would advise you to add it yourself to the HTML file because the library is very unlikely to add such a feature judging by how versatile it is and the many shapes the media library input can take.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how to properly add that in the Nova? A field that is not a field in fact?